# How can I hook onto onCreate of the Activity in an Android instrumentation test?

Tags: android, android-testing

I want to execute some code in my instrumentation test after my Activity's `onCreate` but before its `onResume`. Is there any way I can achieve this in the test code, without modifying production code?

My test class extends `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. It's a gradle project running under the latest Android Studio.